# Vanadurga mahavidya mantra translation

Tags: mantras

samudrah uttare teere
dvivido nama vanarah
tasya mutra purishabhyam
hutasanasya samaya samaya svaha
.... this is one mantra given in vanadurga mahavidya pancasati. can anyone decode this, give the source and the meaning please.